# Julia: loop over rows of matrix (or not)

Tags: matrix, iterator, julia

Say I have a vector of strings like this

```
julia> R = ["ABC","DEF"]
2-element Vector{String}:
"ABC"
"DEF"
```

Now I duplicate the elements to form a 2*2 matrix:

```
julia> x = [R R]
2×2 Matrix{String}:
"ABC"  "ABC"
"DEF"  "DEF"
```

What I want to achieve is to concatenate the strings from each row of the matrix. The best I could come up with is

```
julia> [join(x[i,:]) for i in 1:length(x)÷2]
2-element Vector{String}:
"ABCABC"
"DEFDEF"
```

which gives the desired result.

Are there alternative solutions (without an explicit loop)? I tried to find a working syntax with broadcasting but failed.

(Another idea I tried was

```
julia> x = [R,R]
2-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
["ABC", "DEF"]
["ABC", "DEF"]

julia> join.(x)
2-element Vector{String}:
"ABCDEF"
"ABCDEF"
```

which is "simpler" but obviously does not give the desired result.)

Comment: In case you are actually starting from `R` rather than from the matrix, you could just do `repeat.(R, 2)` instead of forming the matrix

Comment: Yes, I am starting from `R`. --- Oh, `repeat.` is also a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I wound up with a few options for applying function to the **rows** of the matrix:

```
julia> x = ["ABC" "ABC"; "DEF" "DEF"]
2×2 Matrix{String}:
 "ABC"  "ABC"
 "DEF"  "DEF"
```

## 1. map-like synatax using `mapslices`

The function you are looking for might be `mapslices(f, A; dims)`:

```
julia> mapslices(join, x; dims=[2])
2×1 Matrix{String}:
 "ABCABC"
 "DEFDEF"
```

It's a "map" called on "slices" of the array instead of the elements, along the dimensions given by `dims`.

## 2. broadcasting syntax using `eachrow`

`eachrow(A::AbstractVecOrMat)` creates an iterator over the rows of the matrix, returning array **view** for each.

```
julia> join.(eachrow(x))
2-element Vector{String}:
 "ABCABC"
 "DEFDEF"
```

## 3. Combining plain `map` and `eachrow`

```
julia> map(join, eachrow(x))
2-element Vector{String}:
 "ABCABC"
 "DEFDEF"
```

The performance of the three approaches appears to be identical on 100x100 random array using BenchmarkTools:

| method | performance |
| --- | --- |
| 1. `@btime mapslices(join, x; dims=[2])` | 1.379 ms (21935 allocations: 4.92 MiB) |
| 2. `@btime join.(eachrow(x))` | 1.296 ms (21206 allocations: 4.82 MiB) |
| 3. `@btime map(join, eachrow(x))` | 1.294 ms (21304 allocations: 4.82 MiB) |

(with small overhead for more flexible mapslices)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution. Let me add another not-quite-right approach to the question.

Comment: Oh yes, if you have control over how the matrix is formed, you can handle the issue there :-)

Comment: Right, but your answer is perfect as it adresses the question (how to loop over the rows).

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you say in the comments that you are starting from `R`, there's no point to form `x` to get what you're after, just repeat the elements of `R` directly:

```
julia> repeat.(R, 2) == join.(eachrow([R R]))
true

julia> @btime repeat.($R, 2);
  61.283 ns (3 allocations: 128 bytes)

julia> @btime join.(eachrow([$R $R]));
  354.392 ns (11 allocations: 704 bytes)
```

in this case it allocates roughly a quarter and is 5 times faster.

EDITed to add a benchmark that's closer to the other answer - a 100-element vector of lenght 3 random strings:

```
julia> using Random

julia> R = [randstring(3) for _ ∈ 1:100];

julia> @btime join.(eachrow([$R for _ ∈ 1:100]));
  1.607 ms (1103 allocations: 138.62 KiB)

julia> @btime repeat.($R, 100);
  43.497 μs (101 allocations: 33.69 KiB)
```

so here we have more like a factor of 40 difference in timings (although it's less obvious what to benchmark now because in addition to benchmarking the concatenation of the different rows of `x` one could think of different ways to construct `x` from `R` with different levels of efficiency)